# Abstract class not generating with CodeDom

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, metaprogramming, codedom

I have this class definition:

```
CodeTypeDeclaration helloWorldClass = new CodeTypeDeclaration("HelloWorld") {
     Attributes = MemberAttributes.Abstract | MemberAttributes.Public
};
```

Why does this declaration generates a *non-abstract* class?

```
public class HelloWorld
{
}
```

Comment: May be `TypeAttributes = TypeAttributes.Abstract` ?

Comment: That was it!! Why did they add a `Attributes` property if it does nothing when defining a type?

Comment: @MatiCicero Because they are `MemberAttributes`, they apply to a member, not the type.

Comment: I think `Attributes` are for fields, properties, methods etc.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov But why does `CodeTypeDeclaration` extends from a class named `CodeTypeMember` if it is not a member?

Comment: @MatiCicero Because a type can be a *member* of a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`CodeTypeDeclaration.TypeAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codetypedeclaration.typeattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `MemberAttributes`:

```
CodeTypeDeclaration helloWorldClass = new CodeTypeDeclaration("HelloWorld") 
{
     TypeAttributes = TypeAttributes.Abstract | TypeAttributes.Public
};
```

> Why did they add a Attributes property if it does nothing when
>   defining a type?

That is specified explicitly in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codetypedeclaration.typeattributes(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Some of the flags such as Abstract overlap with the meaning of flags
>   in the Attributes property of CodeTypeDeclaration that is inherited
>   from CodeTypeMember. **The Attributes property is a side effect of the
>   CodeTypeDeclaration class inheriting from CodeTypeMember so that
>   classes can be nested. The flags in the TypeAttributes property should
>   be used instead of the flags in the Attributes property.**

In order to use such an inheritance hierarchy, they made a slight confusion duplication. That's why good documentation is important.

Comment: @MatiCicero Welcome. Glad it made sense.